# How to create template for cakephp paginator?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to apply bootstrap 4 pagination style in cakephp paginator helper.

It is looking very hard to me.

This my simple html that I want to apply in paginator helper

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I created a paginator-templates file in config location.

config/paginator-templates.php

```
return [
    'number' => '<a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
];
```

Then I have initialized in appView.php

```
public function initialize(): void
{
       $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']);
}
```

After that getting below error

```
Config file "paginator-templates.php" did not return an array
```

How can I create a `paginator-templates.php` for apply bootstrap 4 pagination design in cakephp ? Has there any blog or example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the file returning?

One way to work around this might be to use the `setTemplate()` method on the helper.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#changing-templates-at-run-time

Using your supplied example code I've been able to get the code working in Cake 3.8.5

I wonder if you just forgot the opening `<?php` tag in your templates file so it's coming back as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your template file needs be surrounded with "<?php"  "?>".
That is missing from the example in the documentation.